# Adding a lot of includes in Eclipse CDT Paths&Symbols

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, include-path

I'm trying to work with [Soclib](http://www.soclib.fr)(www.soclib.fr) inside the Eclipse CDT 3.8, but the code error highlighter (analyser, whatever is called) do not see a huge bunch of include files. The compilation is not a problem because Makefile calls a python script that deals with dependencies etc. but I want Eclipse CDT to be useful, and show me if I am doing something wrong.

I tried to add the root folder of all includes as a separate folder in the workbench and then add it to the right click on project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols as a folder from workspace. It doesn't work. 
If I try to the root folder of it at the same place, it doesn't work ( Eclipse doesn't treat this folder recursively, so the entry here needs to be a leaf of the tree).

One way it could work is to make a python/bash script that would go through the tree and create a list of all end leaves with .h or .hpp files, and then to import that list to Eclipse. Is there a smarter/easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Saw the same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900370/eclipse-kepler-cdt-include-external-header-files-add-external-include-path-rec

Answer (score 2):

Based on the previous answer I have made a convenient Python script to generate the XML file for Eclipse for C and C++ . Feel free to use it.

[CDT XML Generator GitHub](https://github.com/hornmich/cdt_includes_gen/)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I made a python script that creates an XML file that I import to Eclipse:

```
import os

list = os.popen('find . -type d').read()
fd = list.split('\n')
fd.pop()

d = '/home/milos/soclib'

OutputFile = open('symbols.xml', 'w')
OutputFile.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
OutputFile.write ('<cdtprojectproperties>\n')
OutputFile.write ('<section name="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.wizards.settingswizards.IncludePaths">\n')
OutputFile.write ('<language name="C++ Source File">\n')

for f in fd:
    if 'include' in f:
        if not '.svn' in f:
            if not 'platform' in f:
                OutputFile.write('<includepath>' + d + f[1:] + '</includepath>' + '\n')
OutputFile.write('</language>\n')
OutputFile.write('<section>\n')
OutputFile.write('<cdtprojectproperties>\n')
OutputFile.close()
```

I just run this script in the root folder of the simulator and get all include folders I need, and then just import it to Eclipse

Comment: How do you **import** it?