# Eclipse Kepler CDT include external header files / Add External Include Path recursively ( with subfolders )

Tags: eclipse-cdt, include-path

Hi I have a embedded C project and all the basic C libraries are stored in an external folder ( not in the workspace ). I can compile because the compiler knows where to look for this files, but Eclipse does not know that these files exist and I get error messages: 
[image]

I can manually add one folder with: `rightClickOnProject->Properties->C/C++ Include Paths and
Symbols -> Add External Include Path`

For example the file `<stdint.h>` is located in the folder `C:\embARM7\yagarto\arm-elf\include` so I do the following:

[image]

This solves the eclipse error marker for `<stdint.h>`

But the file `<stdio.h>` is located in the folder `C:\embARM7\yagarto\arm-elf\include\sys` and I have to make the whole process again for:

[image]

Now the next header file is located in `C:\embARM7\yagarto\arm-elf\include\machine` and so on and so forth....

My Question is : 
Is there a way to add an external include path with ALL subfolders ?
Kind of "add this folder and all subfolders" / "add this folder recursively".
Like `C:\embARM7\yagarto\arm-elf\include\*` so that I do not have to add every folder in the folder structure manually. For one project this is 5 minutes but I have to do it for 10 projects and this work kind of sucks.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problems with the very common:  
`C:/xxx/Cygwin/usr/include`  
where all internal directories like `libxml2` are not included.  
No solution yet.

Answer (score 6):

I also came across the same issue while to add set of external headers into my project. Instead of using include Paths and Symbols in the Project Properties, I added to my project a link to the root directory which contains all the external headers within its sub-directory. This is how to do it:

1. `rightClickOnProject->New->Folder`,
2. Click on `Advanced` button in the `New Folder` dialog box,
3. select `Link to alternate location` option box,
4. Browse to your the root directory containing all your headers, and
5. Hit the `Finish`button.

Cheers

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if there are files in the link folder which have unmet dependancies,you are forced to solve those dependancies first in order to proceed with your development irrespective if you need those files. Example if the link folder has a header file "header1.h" including another header file "header2.h", then one has to make sure that header2.h is available irrespective of if you are including header1.h or not in your source file. I think eclipse parses all the files which are present in the link folder. This is not the case if you use External Path-Include.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such option neither in Eclipse 3.7-4.3 nor in MS VS2012. Apparently the workaround is to write a script in any language which would generate the recursive path for you.

For Eclipse, you can write an .xml file with project settings and then import it (Project properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Import Settings...). To make an idea of the structure of this file, start by exporting your current project settings somewhere.